# Localised sub-paths with react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localization, react-router, react-router-redux

So I am converting a large existing application to React. Our localised content is like this:

```
www.website.com/about      // english
www.website.com/es/about   // spanish
www.website.com/de/about   // german
```

So I need to declare routes for each locale, I assume like this:

```
<Route path='/' component={App} />
<Route path='/es' component={App} />
<Route path='/de' component={App} />
```

I am wondering if there is a more terse way of doing this, though?

Also, I would like all links to respect the base path, eg:

```
<Link to='/inbox' />
```

Would automatically go to `/es/inbox` if that user's locale is Spanish. There must be a pre-existing or common way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use params with react router. So something like

```
<Route path='/:language' component={App} />
```

So in the components you can access this.props.params.language will have whatever which is navigated. So in the component you can handle those logic

Comment: Yes, I was considering this. The problem with this is I obviously have js and css hosted at the same location, so trying to get `www.website.com/dist/bundle.js` interprets `/dist` as a locale.

Comment: I'm not sure what server you are using, but it should be serving static content in a way that URLs for static content never reach your route matching code.

Answer (score -3):

**One approach**

You can keep `locale` or something else as static `route` for `language` params.

As an example

Your links will be like

```
www.website.com/locale/en/about    // english
www.website.com/locale/es/about   // spanish
www.website.com/locale/de/about   // german
```

And routes will be something like this.

```
<Route path='/locale'/>
  <Route path='en' component={App} />
  <Route path='es' component={App} />
  <Route path='de' component={App} />
</Route>
```

Comment: From an SEO perspective that is a ridiculous solution.

Comment: In that case move `www.website.com/dist/bundle.js` to `www.website.com/dist/js/bundle.js` or something else. And keep language as `/:language` (direct params)